# Who cannot be the Prime Minister of the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitution, prime-minister

Other than the ability to survive votes of confidence, are there any rules on who may or may not be Prime Minister of the UK? E.g. could the monarch be the PM? Could a non-UK-national? Could a minor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UK constitution is based, in part, on tradition and convention.

By tradition, the Prime Minister must be a member of the House of Commons. As such they must be 18 or over and a British, Irish or Commonwealth citizen. They cannot be a noble, though it is possible to renounce one's hereditary position in order to stand for Parliament. The Queen is also not a commoner, so can't be an MP in the House of Commons, and so can't be Prime Minister. Certain other people are not eligible to be an MP: Civil servants, Police Officers, Judges, Bishops, Soldiers, though they are free to become MPs (and PM) after leaving their post.

However, the advantage of an unwritten constitution is that it can be bent as the need requires.  There is no written constitutional requirement for a Prime Minister (although many recent acts of Parliament refer to the post) The title is unofficial (and began as a term of derision); the official post is "First Lord of the Treasury". So there is no written rule that says the PM must be an MP, there is no written rule that says the Queen can't pick her favourite horse to be PM.

But you shouldn't interpret this to mean that the Queen has a free hand to pick whoever she chooses. Tradition is as important to the UK constitution as the Supreme Court is to the US constitution. To ignore the strict requirements of tradition is as incorrect as ignoring the rulings of the Supreme Court in understanding the Constitution of USA.

So short answers are

1. No, the Queen cannot be PM
2. Yes, a foreign national can be PM (if they are Irish, or from a qualifying Commonwealth country)
3. No, a child may not be PM.

Comment: Re commoners: "Although popularly considered to refer to the fact its members are commoners, the actual name of the House of Commons comes from the Norman French word for communities – _communes_." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Commons_of_the_United_Kingdom)). Not all MPs are commoners; some of them are knights and, as you mention, hereditary peers.

Comment: Re people not eligible to be MPs: it might be worth clarifying that people can't continue to serve in those roles while being an MP, but _former_ holders of those posts can become MPs.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the reason the Queen can't be an MP is because of her role in the [Queen-in-Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen-in-Parliament), which makes her already part of the legislature.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff that is interesting,  Knights are "gentry"  not "nobility".  The Queen can't be an MP because she is the Queen, and the Queen can't be an MP.  Let's not overthink this!

Comment: Isn't over-thinking things the point of this website? :-)

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff, James K: the queen being any sort of minister or holding any sort of office is as nonsensical as the queen having a passport or a driver's license.  These ministers and officers exercise power nominally delegated to them by the queen.  If the queen were to take that power back for herself, she would eliminate the office to which it is delegated, not assume that office.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alec_Douglas-Home?wprov=sfla1 is an example (within living memory) of how far the constitution can be stretched to accommodate a PM who is not currently an MP (or eligible to be one)

Comment: Although it is unusual nowadays for the Prime Minister not to be a member of the House of Commons, there has been one in my lifetime, namely Sir Alec Douglas-Home. (Lord Home). However before he was called to the Palace, it was always understood that he would renounce his peerage, and stand in a by-election - which he duly won. However in the nineteenth century it was often the case that the PM was a member of the House of Lords. I believe that is how the office of "Leader of the House" came into being - the holder being the Government leader in the Commons.